# How to plot Bifurcation of Quartic Polynomial Vector Fields

Tags: ode, complex-numbers, maxima

I try to replot [Bifurcation of Quartic Polynomial Vector Fields](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/Xi0rKWVsxOc).

[image]

It is the complex ODE dz/dt = p(z) = z^4 + O(z^2), where the four roots of p(z) are pictured as the black dots: one fixed at the origin, and the remaining three forming the vertices of an equilateral triangle centered at the origin and rotating.

First I try to find p(z) [by creating polynomial with desired properities:](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Mathematics/Vector_field#rboyce1000) p(z) = z* f(z)

- z has a one root at origin
- f(z) should have 3 [roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#Explicit_expressions_in_low_degrees) f(z) = z^2+z+1

so  p(z)

```
 p(z) = z(z^2 + z + e^{2\pi i t})
```

has 4 roots

I try to draw it using Maxima CAS

```
r:realpart(z*(z^2+z+1));
m:imagpart(z*(z^2+z+1));
plotdf([r,m],[x,y]);
```

but the result seems bad:
[image]

How should I do it properly ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found first error:

```
p(z) = z (z^3+ e^(2*pi*i*t))
```

so for z(z^3-1)

[image]

Image made with [program by MAKS SURGUY](https://msurguy.github.io/flow-lines/?xf=x*%28%28-3*x*y%5E2%29%2Bx%5E3-1%29-y*%283*x%5E2*y-y%5E3%29&yf=x*%283*x%5E2*y-y%5E3%29%2By*%28%28-3*x*y%5E2%29%2Bx%5E3-1%29)