# How to plot 2D vector field in Maxima CAS?

Tags: visualization, numerical-methods, maxima

I want to draw [2d Vector field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76347166/how-to-plot-bifurcation-of-quartic-polynomial-vector-fields) in Maxima CAS

```
display2d:false;
kill(all);
t:0.75*%i;
p:z*(z^3-1.5^3*%e^(2*%pi*%i*t));
s:solve([p],[z]);
s:map(rhs,s);
s:map('float,s);
s:map('rectform,s);

p:rectform(p);
r:realpart(p);
m:imagpart(p);
plotdf([r,m],[x,y], [trajectory_at,realpart(s[2]), imagpart(s[2])], [direction,forward]);
```

My code computes roots but could not find real and imaginary part of p :

```
[0.05196989408769048*(5.196152422706631*%i-3.0),
   -0.05196989408769048*(5.196152422706631*%i+3.0),0.3118193645261429,0.0]
(%i6) s:map('rectform,s)
(%o6) [0.2700434910715599*%i-0.1559096822630714,
   (-0.2700434910715599*%i)-0.1559096822630714,0.3118193645261429,0.0]
(%i7) z:x+y*i
(%o7) i*y+x
(%i8) p:rectform(p)
(%o8) z*(z^3-3.375*%e^-(1.5*%pi))
(%i9) r:realpart(p)
(%o9) z*(z^3-3.375*%e^-(1.5*%pi))
(%i10) m:imagpart(p)
(%o10) 0
(%i11) plotdf([r,m],[x,y],[trajectory_at,realpart(s[2]),imagpart(s[2])],
          [direction,forward])
plotdf: expression(s) given can only depend on x and y
Found extra variable z  -- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);
```

How should I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

first error :

```
 t:0.75*%i;
```

should be

```
t:0.75;
```

```
(%i11) plotdf([r,m],[x,y],[trajectory_at,realpart(s[2]),imagpart(s[2])],
              [direction,forward])
Wrong argument for plot option "trajectory_at". Expecting a real number
                                 but found "
                                0.25*(1.5*sqrt(3)-2.598076211353315)".
```

so still not working